# Using form_for tag with get method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am trying to Submit a form using get method. Earlier I was trying a similar thing with form_tag and it was working but now when I changed to a form_for tag, this doesn't seem to work.

```
<%- filter_path = params[:action] == "index" ? posts_path : sneak_peek_posts_path %>
<%= form_for(@post_filter, :url=> filter_path, :method => :get) do |f| %>
```

I get a no routes error.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can pass the raw HTML attributes using `:html` if you need to. For Rails 3:

```
<%= form_for(@post_filter, :url=> filter_path, :html => { :method => 'GET' }) do |f| %>
```

**Update** and in Rails 4, per @andre.orvalho's suggestion below, the `method` parameter can be supplied directly:

```
<%= form_for(@post_filter, url: filter_path, method: :get ) do |f| %>
```

Comment: you should update your answer to rails 4: <%= form_for(@post_filter, url: filter_path, method: :get ) do |f| %>

Comment: Using just `method: :get` without the `:html =>` works on Rails 3.2 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
<%= form_for(@post_filter, :url=> filter_path, :html => {:method => :get}) do |f| %>
```