# save form data to variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I am playing with Venmo's API, and I am wondering if the following scenerio is possible.
The Venmo Payment Link API only requires certain elements within the URL, mainly Transaction Type, Recepient, Amount, and Note. (https://developer.venmo.com/docs/payment-links)

I am wondering if I can create a form somewhere in my views and have the user input the desirable venmo fields, and then when he press submit, the link will automatically be the venmo payment link?

I have the following code to convert the desirable input type to the payment link, I just need to find some way to link such method to my application.

```
email = "example@example.com"
amount = 100
note = "HELLO WORLD"

if email.include? "@"
  email.sub!("@", "%40")
end

if note.include? " "
  note.gsub!(" ", "%20")
end

puts "https://venmo.com/?txt=pay%receipts=#{email}&amount=#{amount}&note=#{note}&audience=public"
```

Comment: Wouldn't setting form method to GET solve that?

Comment: sorry, but I am still news to rails app. Can you explain in more details please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742417/using-form-for-tag-with-get-method.

Comment: I am looking at the solution (<%= form_for(@post_filter, url: filter_path, method: :get ) do |f| %>) , but not sure how each fields can be stored in a variable, manipulated, and then resubmit as a link. Can you explain please?