# Cannot set form_tag method as get

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I try to send a form_tag with get method like this

```
= form_tag search_offers_path, method: :get, class: 'sort-form form inputs-underline' do
              .sort-inputs
                .input-group.inputs-underline.min-width-150px.sort-input
                  = label_tag :sort_by, 'Sort by'
                  = select_tag :sort_by, options_for_select([["Sort by", ""], ["User level", "user_level"], ["Success rating", "user_average_overall_rating"]]), class: "form-control"
                .input-group.inputs-underline.min-width-150px.sort-input
                  = label_tag :sort_direction, 'Sort direction'
                  = select_tag :sort_direction, options_for_select([["Sort direction", ""], ["Ascending", "asc"], ["Descending", "desc"]]), class: "form-control"
```

But I don't understand why it becomes a POST as form_tag default

```
Started POST "/offers/search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-04 12:35:18 +0700

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/offers/search"):
```

Anyone has a hint?

UPDATE: I checked the HTML generated based on the feedback and see that data-remote = true (although I have never set it and I don't want an ajax request, too).

Comment: can you share your `routes.rb` code?

Comment: Are you submitting this form via ajax?

Comment: Please check & share the html generated by this code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using form\_for tag with get method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742417/using-form-for-tag-with-get-method)

Comment: @Gabbar: From rails routes. I think it's OK as I submit another form with button_to (method get) to the same search_offers_path and it is a get.  search_offers GET    (/:locale)/offers/search(.:format)            offers#search {:locale=>/en|vi/} . This is from rails routes.

Comment: @Emu: I don't think so. But I submit it using jquery with change method, as this is a dropdown

Comment: @emu @Salil. Wait you might be right. As I check the html generated, I notice there is data-remote = "true" here. Although I have not set it in slim. `<form class="sort-form form inputs-underline" action="/offers/search" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">`

Comment: @Manishh Why it duplicated? I want to use a form_tag as I have no model here?

Comment: Can you share routes.rb code?

Comment: routes.rb code : `resources :offers, only: %i[new show index], param: :code do
      collection do
        get :search
      end
    end`

Comment: <%= form_tag({}, {:method => :get}) do %>

Please try this syntax once.

Comment: @sam How can add a class to this syntax?

Comment: <%= form_tag({}, {:method => :get, class: 'sort-form form inputs-underline'}) do %>

Comment: @sam, this syntax successfully fixed my problem. Now I can send a GET method. Strange. Can you make this an answer?

Comment: What is the rails version? Your code did work for me I am using rails 4.2.10.

Comment: @Manishh I use 5.1.0. Actually I have used form_tag many times before as the same as above with this version, and it worked.

Comment: @lan Tran, Please vote it if you get the solution so that other can check my answer properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag({}, {:method => :get, class: 'sort-form form inputs-underline'}) do %>
```

Try this one. You can definitely get your solution.